# Coordnate mapping on xarray dataset/datarray

Tags: python, python-xarray

What is the recommended way to implemen coordinate mapping between xarray data?

Here is my example/case:

I have one DataArray `ndo3_1` with the following coordinates "[time, **plev**, lat, lon]". Then I have another DataArray `h` with also "[time, **plev**, lat, lon]".

(**plev** is pressure_level and **h** is height)

I need to convert "ndo3_1[time, **plev**, lat, lon]" to "ndo3_2[time, **h**, lat, lon]". As you can see `h` is only a conversion matrix for `plev` as some models are easier to represent with equal pressures. However others are easier with height.

Is it possible to achieve this?
Which would be the recommended way?

Note "for" loop in python would be really slow, the correct answer would use a functional approach using xarray operations.

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure if this helps:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

# create DataArrays
plev = np.arange(1, 100)
lat = np.arange(-90, 91)
lon = np.arange(-180, 181)
time = np.arange(0, 365)

x = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(len(time), len(plev), len(lat), len(lon)),
                 coords=[('time', time), ('plev', plev), ('lat', lat), ('lon', lon)])

h = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(len(time), len(plev), len(lat), len(lon)),
                 coords=[('time', time), ('plev', plev), ('lat', lat), ('lon', lon)])

# create interpolation function
f = interp1d(plev, h.plev, fill_value='extrapolate', axis=1)

# create new array
ndo3_2 = xr.DataArray(np.zeros(x.shape), coords=[('time', time), ('plev', h.plev), ('lat', lat), ('lon', lon)])

# interpolate
ndo3_2.plev = f(x.plev)

# print
print(ndo3_2)
```